# why does NSApplication sharedApplication mainMenu return nil?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmenu, nsapplication, nsstoryboard

Apple's docs say:

> All of an application’s menus in the menu bar are owned by one NSMenu
>   instance that’s created by the application when it starts up. You can
>   retrieve this main menu with the NSApplication method mainMenu.

I have the following is in my delegate class to obtain the app's menu:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification{
  NSMenu *mainMenu=[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainMenu];
}
```

why is `mainMenu` nil? Am I calling it at the wrong time? Putting `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainMenu]` in my view controller's `loadView` also returns nil.

All I want to do is add items to the application menu bar.

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? Did you create a new project and tried you code there? It's working for me from a view controller (haven't tested applicationDidFinishLoading but it should work too.

Comment: @HAS you are right, it works for new Cocoa Application projects. I have moved my files to the new project!

Comment: glad it helped :) If you have time and find the issue please answer your own question (and maybe file a bug report at bugreport.apple.com). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The code returns nil because the associated Storyboard does not have an Application Scene/menu bar.

Creating a new Cocoa Application project with xcode built all this for me and I just had to port my files over. The code above now returns NSMenu as expected.